# A value of type 'Future<void>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<DeviceModel>'

Tags: flutter, api, dart

[image]

I am unsure on how to resolve this. I am trying to grab a specific device from an endpoint on my API.

```
class DeviceProfileWidget extends StatelessWidget {
 final int deviceId;
 DeviceProfileWidget({Key? key, required this.deviceId}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Future<DeviceModel> device = Get.find<DeviceController>. 
  ().getDevice(AppConstants.DEVICE_URI + deviceId.toString());
  var ports = device.ports;
  var port = ports.length;
  print("device id is " + device.deviceId);
```

I can see that I am getting the data when I print my response.body in my device_api_client.dart file.  However I am struggling to get this file to pass the deviceId so that I can grab a specific device. I dont want to grab the device from a filtered list, I want to hit the specific endpoint for the particular device. I can share more of my code if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

getDevice method is located here in controller file

```
class DeviceController extends GetxController {
 final DeviceRepo deviceRepo;
 DeviceController({required this.deviceRepo});
 DeviceModel? _deviceModel;
 DeviceModel? get device => _deviceModel;

 Future<DeviceModel> getDevice(deviceURI) async {
   Response response = await deviceRepo.getDevice(deviceURI);
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     _deviceModel = DeviceModel.fromJson(
      response.body['device'] as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
     // print(_deviceModel);
     update();
   } else {
     print("no data");
   }
    return DeviceModel(
       deviceId: device!.deviceId,
       publicId: device!.publicId,
       label: device!.label,
       temperatureImperial: device!.temperatureImperial, ports: 
       device!.ports);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In getDevice method please change the return to Future <DeviceModel> and return a DeviceModel from the method. Right now it's returning nothing and marked as Future<void>
You can pass it to this method by making those parameters

```dart
Future<DeviceModel> getDevice(deviceid, uri)
{
   // All computation here
   return DeviceModel(
//add device model details here like device ID etc
    );
}
```

To get the deviceData use

```
DeviceModel deviceData = await getDevice();
```

Comment: when I do this and set device to Future<DeviceModel> then I cant drill down into device and utilize the items within the object. I am unsure how to proceed with this.

Comment: I need to be able to pass my device URI and device ID to the getDevice method in the controller so that I grab the correct device though. The getDevice method is in the controller file.